# Detect when WPF/WInForm/Android runtime is included in a project

Tags: c#, android, wpf, winforms

I have an Extension class I share within multiple projects where the project can be Android (Xamarin/.NET MAUI) but also a WinForm/WPF app or even a WinForm one with some WPF windows and I'm wondering if there are existing preprocessor macros to enable or disable some code, e.g. 'System.Data.SqlClient' stuff is not available on Android and 'System.Windows' (which I have some extensions) is not part of a WinForm project unless some dll are manually referenced (such PresentationCore, PresentationFramework, WindowsBase, WindowsFormsIntegration etc.). So my question is:
is there any preprocessor macro to enable/disable code for Android, WPF and WinForm at compile time?

what i would is something like:

```
#if !(ANDROID_RUNTIME)
public static string SqlDataReaderStringExt(this SqlDataReader reader, int i) 
{
    ...
}
#endif

#if WPF_RUNTIME
....
#endif

#if WINFORM_RUNTIME
....
#endif
```

so, stop manually comment the code in each project.

Comment: See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/d-preprocessor-definitions?force_isolation=true&view=msvc-170

Comment: Thanks for the link. Anyway I'm looking for existing definitions if any . When said shared, I mean that I share my code also with collaborators so I can't setup any project for them by creating additional macros for a target configuration. Thanks anyway

Comment: Look at example on the page.  The directives allows you to enable/disable the options or pass option on command line of compiler.

Comment: You were right. Even on Android the macro __ANDROID__ (with trailing/leading double underscore) are added by Visual Studio, so now I understand that cannot be mutch to do with it other than add macros unde conditional compilation symbols. For a moment I became nostalgic for old projects written in plain c, but c# works other way